# Is it possible to make a DataGridView, DataGridColumn, DataGridCell mimic a specific behaviour in excel?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datagridview, datagridcolumn, datagridcell

Technologies: Visual Studio .NET 2008

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a way to force a column in a datagridview to behave similarily to Excel.

Currently, this is what the data looks like:

```
A) 123456789.02211
```

what I would like to see is

```
B) 123,456,789.02
```

However, the catch is, I want the data to look like "B" when not in use (no focus, mouse isn't in cell) and I want the data to look like "A" when in use. (Cell has focus, not the whole column.)

If I can't do the specific cell, that's fine. If it's as broad as "When the dataGridview has focus, all data looks like A, I can deal with that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at `Me.myDataGridView.Columns(x).DefaultCellStyle.Format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the DataGridView's [`CellBeginEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit.aspx) and [`CellEndEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx) events.  The `CellBeginEdit` event will allow you to format the cell you're about to edit and the `CellEndEdit` event will allow you to reset the cell's format back after editing is complete.

Like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex != indexOfMyDateColumn) {    // Don't custom format all columns.
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Format = "F5" };
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex != indexOfMyDateColumn) {    // Don't custom format all columns.
       dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Format = "N2" };
    }
}
```

Both the `CellBeginEdit` and the `CellEndEdit` events have EventArg properties that you can use to determine if (and/or how) you want to format your cells.  My example uses the `e.ColumnIndex` property to ensure that my date column is not formatted.

You might need different formatting strings but this is the general approach you're looking for.

Comment: I can't yet test this, but when you enter CellBeginEdit and the format changes, would it preserve all the decimals?

Comment: @Christian Yep. Changing the `Style` property like this doesn't affect the underlying data.  Give it a try.

Comment: There's a few more pressing issues in my application, but once those are closed up I'll give this a shot, but it looks like this is the answer. Will confirm once I try it out.

Comment: So it does seem like a good solution, but my problems are that it doesn't format the values on startup, and the new version doesn't allow the user to edit a cell, just select it. I changed the event to CellClick and CellLeave and that worked, but I guess I should have mentioned that there's also a column with a Date in it that gets messed up. I'm going to try and focus the change on only two columns.

Comment: Could you not just set the cell format at the same time you populate the DGV?

Comment: @Christian As @CodeBlend wrote, you can set a starting cell format that works for you.  Also, the `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` events include info on which column the event is firing for in the event args' `ColumnIndex` property.  You can use this to avoid custom formatting your date column.  I updated my answer to show this.